# insert doesn't retrieve key from hash function

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, hashmap, unordered-map

I am trying to store a Struct into a map using a hash function for the key. When creating two identical objects, I do get an identical key from the hash function however each element is still inserted in the map.

Here are my codes:

```
// Key
struct GridrecordKey {
    // Keys
    double key1;
    double key2;
    ...

    GridrecordKey() {
        key1 = 0;
        key2 = 0;
        ...
    }

    bool operator==(const GridrecordKey &other) const {
        return (key1 == other.key1
             && key2 == other.key2);
    }
};

// Hash function
struct GridrecordKeyHasher
{
    std::size_t operator()(const GridrecordKey& k) const
    {
        using boost::hash_value;
        using boost::hash_combine;

        // Start with a hash value of 0    .
        std::size_t seed = 0;

        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(k.key1));
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(k.key2));

        // Return the result.
        return seed;
    }
};

// Record
struct gridrecord {
    double element1;
    double element2;
...
};
```

Sample of my main program:

```
 int main() {
        GridrecordKey key; // The key
        gridrecord record; // The record
        unordered_map<GridrecordKey, gridrecord, GridrecordKeyHasher> map;  // The map

        // Modify the key and insert record into map
        key.key1 = 1;
        map.insert({ key, record });

        // Keep the same key and try to insert another record into the map
        key.key1 = 1;

        // Here the record is added to the map while it should't as this 
        // key already exist
        auto x = map.insert({ key, record }); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean each element is still inserted? The line should execute despite having duplicate keys

Comment: What I mean is that two records are added in the map while there should be only one as the key is the same

Comment: Why do you say that the two records are both added? See answer below for some context

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code and printed the count of elements that are in your map after you inserted two times the same element:

```
std::cout << map.size() << std::endl;
--> 1
```

So your code is running as you expected/wanted it.

How do you get to the point that you think it was inserted 2 times?

Comment: My Struct is actually more complicated (including pointer as well). Maybe the problem come from that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a key variable. Its type was char[] and the compare function was not working correctly. Using strcmp() fixed the issue. 
Thank you!